# How to create a global configuration file upgradable

Tags: php

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm creating my own framework, actually all working pretty well. But I need an opinion about this situation. So, I want create a configuration file that can be upgradable by code, by *"upgradable"* I mean that I have the possibility to change the configuration on the application running. Check an example, so I've a default `config.php` file that  is the base configuration of my framework, this file is located inside the root folder. The structure is like this:

```
application      <- APP file
system           <- Framework file
config.php       <- Framework base configuration
index.php
.htaccess
```

the `config.php` is a class that looks like this:

```
class Config
{
    const Language = 'english';
    const DB_HOST  = 'localhost';
}
```

in this file as I said I've the base config of the framework. Now inside my `application` folder I've a directory that contain another `config.php` file and is part of the application.

this file contains an array, that looks like this:

```
$config['LANGUAGE'] = defined('Config::Language') ? Config::LANGUAGE : 'english';
```

So I simply check if in the base `config` file a specific constant is setted or not.

This file is used by my `Setting` class that's an intance of my Framework class.

**THE PROBLEM**

All my request are shunt from `index.php`, in the .htaccess I've my rule `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

So if I change the value of config item, in the `application/config/config.php` I can see the value changed from the current instance, but if I reload the page, for example, I get the default value setted in my `config.php` of my `application` folder. This happen 'cause the instance of `Settings` class is declared each time from:

```
index.php -> Framework load instance [Settings, Controller, Models, etc...] -> Logic Business
```

So how you can see I lost my edit each time a refresh is done.
My `Settings` class looks like this:

```
class Settings
{
    private static $_config = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $file = 'application/config/config.php';
        include $file;
        self::$_config = $config;
    }

    //set or update an item to the global config file
    public static function setItem($name, $value)
    {
        self::$_config[$name] = $value;
    }

    //get a settings from the global config file
    public static function getItem($name)
    {
        if(isset(self::$_config[$name]))
        {
             return self::$_config[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM IN PRACTICE**

the class is very simple to use in the script, for use it I can do something like this:

```
echo Settings::getItem('LANGUAGE');
Settings::setItem('LANGUAGE', 'italian');
echo Settings::getItem('LANGUAGE');
```

the output will be:

```
english
italian
```

but if I refresh the page and don't call `setItem` again, I see even `english` that is declared as default. This drops all the logic for which is designed this class.